# Integration_test ^1.0.2+3 which depends on vm_service >=4.2.0 <7.0.0, vm_service >=4.2.0 <7.0.0 is required

Tags: flutter

Why I can't add an integration test in my pubspec.yaml. Can't someone help me how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This package has been deprecated and the way you have added it in your pubspec is not the correct way. Please try using it like this along with Flutter 2.x.x

```
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test

Comment: I try this step but still can't add this package.

Comment: It works when I use the command flutter pub add integration_test. Actually integration_test: ^1.0.2+3 can't support VM flutter.